# If big bang theory is real.. then why do scientists do not accept "matter CAN disappear to Void"?

Tags: big-bang, states-of-matter

I believe in the big bang theory..
perhaps it was a big lightning not an explosion..
but even that is pretty much same as "big bang theory"..

so matter came from "nothing" (zero).
and existence is "finite" ( returns to zero )

but search for some data on how matter can vanish back to void.. ( nothingess ) via google for example.. and there is no data.

not only there is no data..

there is actually data that suggests matter can not disappear back to void.

how can one not get confused within an evironment where scientists suggest.. "matter came from nothing but can not vanish back to nothing and yet existence is finite"..

seems to be that the whole environment ( earth for example ) is filled with scientists that are simply sayings things in order move on with life. ( telling people what people want to hear rather than logic ) there does not seem to be regard of rationale.

logic is broken..

Comment: What is the void? (Is it the one which formed in my brain after reading this question?)

Comment: Big bang was not an "explosion" but a fast expansion of all the matter, which were condensed on a singular point.

Comment: void is.. a name.. we use.. to describe.. the "organic" state of the "infinity". there is no time no existence nothing.. not even "odds" for an "explosion" to create an "existence" "odd" does not exist and yet.. it happened "once"..

Comment: @V_Programmer it is not correct to define the big bang to have happened at a single point.

Comment: "expension of matter" has go to be a lie. if matter was created from zero originally.. due to random magic kind of a way. i a sure "magic" kept on rolling and matter was simply kept on being created until it slowed down and paused due to "logic" suggesting "it needs to stop".

Comment: if this question does not make sense to you.. perhaps your logic is not inline with the logic of void. but perhaps it slid into a path that has all the politics.. corruption etc. ( e.g. planet earth )

Comment: Physics SE, sadly, deals with mainstream 'rational' physics, and not void physics.

Comment: you see.. the very act of "accepting" that "matter can disappear back to void".. is being able to "imagine" that "matter can disappear" back to void and the very act of being able to "imagine" can change the "state of matter" and thus make it "vanish back to void".. but scientists can not accept it because if they do.. they might vanish.. maybe they vanish before they have a chance to get on tv and tell us about their theory ?

Comment: when i use "void level" .. what i am doing is using absolute "0" to define anything. "mainstream rationale" can be "invalid" and thus.. not to be regarded as "logic" or "rationale" if it can not cope with the effect of a true base "0" .. (void as the base and the standard.. so the b.s. does not effect logic )

Comment: I can't vote to close, but recommend that people do so on the basis of either "unclear what is being asked" or "pet theory".

Comment: Physicists do not believe matter is conserved. We fully believe matter can be created or destroyed. Fusion, for instance, is one example of destroying and creating matter. Energy is conserved locally. Furthermore, the Big Bang was not an explosion nor any kind of event. The Big Bang is a moment of time. Specifically, it is the moment of time when the measured distance between any two distinct points in space approached zero. These facts are easily discoverable on the internet. Google "Big Bang" and the wiki page will undoubtedly confirm this.

Comment: Please do not rush to judge physicists, or anyone, as irrational or illogical merely based on a layman understanding of their profession. It simply isn't polite or justifiable.

Comment: I'm going to be blunt: [physics.se] is not a platform for promoting personal theories. Notice what the tour says about the site *"Physics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for active researchers, academics and students of physics and astronomy."*

Answer (score 3):

Your argument is based upon the idea that all the matter in the universe was created at the moment of the Big Bang. If matter can be created from nothing at the moment of the Big Bang then it does seem reasonable that matter could disappear again, as you say.

The trouble is that there is no experimental or theoretical support for the idea that matter was created at the Big Bang. In fact the Big Bang theory is actually something of a misnomer because the theory specifically excludes the moment of the Big Bang itself. The theory (more precisely the [FLRW metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric)) tells us the geometry of the universe for any time $t > 0$, but does not tell us what happened at $t = 0$. In fact strictly speaking the time $t = 0$ is not part of the universe - general relativity considers the universe to be everything except the moment of the Big Bang itself. We have no theory that tells us what happened at the moment of the Big Bang, so we have no theory that tells us what happened to all the matter in the universe at that moment.

So your argument is not a valid one. We do not know whether matter was created at the Big Bang, so you can't use that claim as evidence that matter can disappear again. This is why Googling has failed to find any support for the idea of disappearing matter.

The closest we have to a theory that tells us what happened at the moment of the Big Bang are speculative ideas from various theories of quantum gravity that suggest there never was a Big Bang but instead a [Big Bounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bounce). If (and it's a big *if*) there is anything to these ideas then we don't have to worry about matter appearing or disappearing. The matter was there before the Big Bounce, made it through the Big Bounce and was still there after the Big Bounce.

Comment: hang on, we know matter was not created at the Big Bang because we know it was created afterwards during leptogenesis, baryogenesis, and BBN.

Comment: @Jimself: no, the matter changed form after the Big Bang (probably when inflation ended) but it wasn't *created* then. What probably happened is the the decay of the inflaton field produced the elementary particles we see today. I'm using the word *matter* to mean *energy* and/or *matter*.

Comment: @JohnRennie Oh, well if by matter you mean energy as well, then I agree. I thought you meant matter as in stuff made of quarks and leptons. I've gotta say, including all forms of energy in "matter" is not a common usage. But I won't say you shouldn't use it

Comment: I've scrubbed a bunch of comments that were not contributing to clarifying John's post. This is a physics site and we expect the users to have a basic familiarity with the discipline.